# How to use firebug api to get page load time

Tags: firebug

I need to fetch the load time of modules present on my web page .Is there anyway I can use firebug api to get load times.

Answer (score 0):

Use the net panel.

Edit: In fact, there is the [performance.timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming) API for your whole webpage. But the Net panel provides you the information you need to get the load times of all the resources seperately. Also see this [blog post](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/support-for-performance-timing-in-firebug/).

Comment: I completed my answer so it might be clearer. I assumed that by module, the author meant "resources" (images, css and js files, etc.)